# Merge Date Ranges Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, date, linq-to-sql

NOTE: This is a linq to sql question and not a general linq question. Linq to SQL has restrictions on what you can do.

I need to merge date ranges to remove overlaps. There is already an existing answer to this question on stackoverflow but the answers cannot be implemented in linq to sql (no recursive CTE, lag, etc.).

[SQL: Merge Date Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653255/sql-merge-date-ranges)

The 2nd answer that uses SQL 92 syntax has a bug in it (if there are rows that intersect with the same end date then these are not considered as overlaps).

Any suggestions?

Thx in advance

Sample data (shamelessly copied from the other stackover flow Q)

PK  | STARTDATE          | ENDDATE

---

1   | 2012/07/21 02:00   | 2012/07/21 04:00
2   | 2012/07/21 03:00   | 2012/07/21 10:00
3   | 2012/07/21 06:00   | 2012/07/21 17:00
4   | 2012/07/21 18:00   | 2012/07/21 19:00

Merging will result in:

PK  | STARTDATE          | ENDDATE

---

1   | 2012/07/21 02:00   | 2012/07/21 17:00
2   | 2012/07/21 18:00   | 2012/07/21 19:00

Comment: Can you fill this question out with some sample data / desired results?

Comment: And if you don't want `sql` answers, best to remove that tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging overlapping time intervals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480031/merging-overlapping-time-intervals)

Comment: This question is specific to linq-to-sql and as such is not a generic linq question - not a duplicate of either of those @gnalck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets create a playfield first:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dateTable](
    [dt_from] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [dt_to] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[dateTable]
           ([dt_from]
           ,[dt_to])
     VALUES 
('2012-07-21 02:00:00', '2012-07-21 04:00:00'),
('2012-07-21 03:00:00', '2012-07-21 10:00:00'),
('2012-07-21 06:00:00', '2012-07-21 17:00:00'),
('2012-07-21 18:00:00', '2012-07-21 19:00:00')
GO
```

We have a bunch of intervals and we want to merge them. We need to find starts and ends of those merged intervals. A merged start must fulfill those constraints:

1. It is a start of some unmerged interval.
2. There is no such interval, that ends at this time or later and starts sooner than this time.
3. If more intervals start at the same time, we take this time only once.

A merged end is simmilar. There is exactly one merged end for every merged start. The only problem may be unmerged intervals, where start is bigger than end. I decided to skip them as invalid. And the code is here

```
var ed = new DataClasses1DataContext();

var res = ed.dateTables
    .Where(d => d.dt_from <= d.dt_to) //change to < for nonzero intervals only
    .Select(f => f.dt_from)
    .Distinct()
    .Where(w => !ed.dateTables.Any(a => a.dt_from < w && a.dt_to >= w))                
    .Select(date => new
    {
        FROM = date,
        TO = ed.dateTables.Select(t => t.dt_to)
        .Where(w => !ed.dateTables.Any(a => a.dt_from <= w && a.dt_to > w) && w >= date)
        .Min()
    }).ToArray();

foreach (var r in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine("FROM: " + r.FROM + " TO: " + r.TO);
}
```

and result here:

```
FROM: 21.07.2012 2:00:00 TO: 21.07.2012 17:00:00 
FROM: 21.07.2012 18:00:00 TO: 21.07.2012 19:00:00
```

the generated SQL is no surprise, just a bit messy

```
SELECT [t1].[dt_from] AS [FROM], (
    SELECT MIN([t3].[dt_to])
    FROM [dbo].[dateTable] AS [t3]
    WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [dbo].[dateTable] AS [t4]
        WHERE ([t4].[dt_from] <= [t3].[dt_to]) AND ([t4].[dt_to] > [t3].[dt_to])
        ))) AND ([t3].[dt_to] >= [t1].[dt_from])
    ) AS [TO]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[dt_from]
    FROM [dbo].[dateTable] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[dt_from] <= [t0].[dt_to]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[dateTable] AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t2].[dt_from] < [t1].[dt_from]) AND ([t2].[dt_to] >= [t1].[dt_from])
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly