# Grouping multiple rows in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 as below

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to transform my table into below :

[image]

The concept of how it work is value will keep the first Start and End Value, I don't know how to explain this with the word, but if I draw this into the table, it would be like this :

[image]

Honestly, I already found a solution for this issue but it only can do with 2 columns, link: [SQL: Merge Date Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653255/sql-merge-date-ranges)

I am always failing while trying to do this with my table.

Thanks! Appreciate any answer or suggestion!

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a Gaps-and-Islands.    Sample data as text is more useful than images

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will try to jump into Gaps-and-Islands articles now

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
Select Sites, Min(Range_Start) as New_Start, Max(Range_End) as New_End
from Table_Name
Group by Sites
```

Comment: this will return a single row and return minimum and maximum value only, I think this cannot applied to mine. thank you for your prompt response bro